# Why is my Observable 'caching' the result of an Async operation?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to listen for some connections using the standard System.Net Socket API and I'm planning on using Reactive Extensions to bridge the gap and create a intuitive way of listening to aforementioned connectionss.

Here's my code so far:

```
public RxConnectionListener(int port, Socket socket, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    _socket = socket;
    // TODO: Lazy binding?
    _socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
    _socket.Listen(0);


    var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
        socket.BeginAccept,
        result => socket.EndAccept(result),
        null);

    _connections = Observable.Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => task)
        ).Select(s => new RxConnection(s))
            .ObserveOn(scheduler)
            .Repeat();
}
```

Now, the socket listening IS working as planned - I'm receiving connections no problem. Issue is, is that the first connection is being received more than once (i.e, it appears `Observable.FromAsync` is caching the result of the async `task` object). I know this is obviously due to the `Repeat()` statement but I was under the impression that wrapping `Observable.FromAsync` inside of `Observable.Defer` and then invoking the `Repeat` on the deferred observable would circumvent the caching - what am I doing wrong?

Subscription code is simply:

```
listener
    .Connections
    .Subscribe(OnNewConnection);
```

Where `listener.Connections` is a property on an instance of `RxConnectionListener` called `Connections` which is backed by `_connections`

`OnNewConnection` is as follows:

```
protected virtual void OnNewConnection(IConnection connection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(connection.RemoteAddress);
}
```

Observed (pun intended) output after trying to connect via TCP once:

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 
::ffff:127.0.0.1 
::ffff:127.0.0.1
::ffff:127.0.0.1
..
(to infinity and beyond)
```

Edit: for completeness, I'm using the `EventLoopScheduler`, although commenting out the `ObserveOn` calls makes no difference.

Comment: FWIW I've used `Observable.Defer` with synchronous `Observables` before and it's worked as intended (no caching of results) - what makes `Observable.FromAsync` special and how do I circumvent this?

Comment: Is there any difference if you use task.ToObservable().Repeat() instead of Observable.FromAsync for creating your connections observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing

```
var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
    socket.BeginAccept,
    result => socket.EndAccept(result),
    null);
```

You created a task getting the next socket connected. If you ask for the task's result twice, you will get the same result both times. That's normal: a task always behaves this way: it runs until it completes, then "caches" its result (be it a normal ending or an exception).

What you meant to do was tu create a function that creates a Task, like this:

```
Func<Task<Socket>> acceptTask = () =>
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(
        socket.BeginAccept,
        result => socket.EndAccept(result),
        null);
};
```

Now, you can create an observable from this Task factory easily: `Observable.FromAsyn(acceptTask)`

Note that it is probably a bad idea to create an observable from a task that you created from the async pattern: there are methods to create the Observable directly from the pattern: save the creation of observables from tasks to the cases where the operations you want to create an observable from are already tasks.

Comment: "there are methods to create the Observable directly from the pattern"
 - these are deprecated as mentioned when addressing @Brizio's answer. Although thank you for mentioning that `Task`s cache, I was not actually aware of this behaviour.

Comment: This actually somewhat solved the issue, although now using HTTP (only as a test client, because it's simpler), I get 3 connections and one read attempt. I'm going to go out on a limb and assume this is because of Chrome being derp, and not the code.

Comment: Yeah, testing it with something else proves that this solves the issue. As you mentioned, the `Task` result was being cached and I wasn't generated a new task, I was simply calling the same (completed) task over and over, which resulted in the same socket being added.

Comment: That's the distinction between a Task and a Fun<Task>. Very important to understand if you wish to make Task-based async code.

Comment: I just overlooked it, aha. I've been using 'factories' as such for a long time now. I just forgot to encapsulate the task factory inside of a function and instead encapsulated the result, woops!

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that the Observable.FromAsync would cache the Result property of the task you're building, therefore the repeat will just give you back the result from the task instead of a new observable every time. 
In order to create a valid repeatable connection you will need to rebuild your task every time. This way the socket result will not be cached anymore.

```
var _connections = Observable.Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => 
    Task.Factory.FromAsync(
    socket.BeginAccept,
    result => socket.EndAccept(result),
    null)))
.Select(s => new RxConnection(s))
.Repeat();
```

Comment: `Observable.FromAsync` has overloads `Func<CancellationToken,Task>`, `Func<Task<TResult>>` (used in OP), `Func<Task>` and `Func<CancellationToken,Task>`. As I am dealing with the raw `System.Net.Socket` class, I do not have the ability to interface with the new `AcceptAsync` method from `TcpListener.`, so I have to wrap it in a `Task<Socket>`.

Comment: Unless, of course, you mean `Observable.FromAsyncPattern` - which is deprecated and actually says that my OP has the correct use case for future use.

Comment: @DanPantry Yes, you're right, didn't realize it was deprecated.

Comment: By looking at the excellent rxx library by Dave Sexton I found that he creates the socket every time in its own implementation of the Rx socket. Even though he still uses FromAsyncPattern I think that his implementation can be safely converted using Task.Factory.FromAsync. You can take a look on http://rxx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest and look for its own ObservableSocket - Accept.cs implementation

Comment: That implementation looks fairly similar to mine, just more condensed in one location.